# Performant way to compare array items to other array items

Tags: c#, arrays, regex

I'm writing a program where I want to check 16,000 strings for about 100 phrases.
My simple way of doing this were two for-loops:
(resulting in 1,600,000 string operations)

```
string[] phrases;    
string[] texts;

for(int t_count = 0; t_count < 16000; t_count++)
{
    for(int p_count = 0; p_count < 100; p_count++)
    {
        Regex pattern = new Regex(phrases[p_count]);
        if (pattern.IsMatch(texts[t_count]))
        {
        //Save phrases[p_count]
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that there must be more effcient ways to do this.
Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: @ J. Steen
Of course it shall run faster, but producing unicorns at the same time would be awesome!

Comment: Efficient how? Time? Memory? Unicorns?

Comment: @J.Steen Unicorns it is!

Comment: We can't help to improve it without more details. Maybe you could use pure string methods instead of regex or a `break` somewhere in the loop. But who knows?

Comment: For example caching the `Regex`(es) would be a start

Comment: Add some examples for the phrases. also an example of //do something would help for better answers

Comment: You can parallelize the task of comparing.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more suited to Code Review? But you'd have to read their policies on the matter.

Comment: I hope this won't become a tit (cons*tit*ution)/ass (cl*ass*) problem :-) (see http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/ )

Comment: You may merge the regexs: regex1|regex2|... but I'm not sure that is a good thing. It is more a question!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start by switching the order of the loops -  rather than compiling each of the 100 regular expressions 16000 times, this would compile them once:

```
for(int p_count = 0; p_count < 100; p_count++)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(phrases[p_count]);
    for(int t_count = 0; t_count < 16000; t_count++)
    {
        if (pattern.IsMatch(texts[t_count]))
        {
        //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And maybe `RegexOptions.Compiled` whould be useful too, but you'd have to profile it to be sure.

Comment: @xantos No, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/R/71b5945bb883860b.html shows the default is `None`.

Comment: If each different regex is only constructed once, leaving RegexOptions.Compiled off should be faster, since the Compiled setting adds initialisation time to the constructor.